# AppleScript to toggle geek tools picture on and off

Tags: applescript

relatively new to coding - I do some music related things and I'm trying to create an overlay to alert me when certain filters are active

geek tools can display a picture which works fine, I can make it appear and disappear, I'm just trying to toggle it on and off

I've got:

```
tell application "GeekTool Helper"
    
set g to geeklet id "C50F8977-88DF-4813-82C3-23D1C23F4624"
    
set visible of g to true

end tell
```

and then the same thing as "false" to make it go away. Again just trying to toggle it back and forth for on one key. I'm sure this is super easy - would really appreciate it if anyone has a sec to help out. Guessing it's some sort of if/then or something...

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this application, but I'm going to assume that your code snippet exemplifies a fully-working script that displays the referenced picture:

> ```
> tell application "GeekTool Helper"
>       set g to geeklet id "C50F8977-88DF-4813-82C3-23D1C23F4624"
>       set visible of g to true
> end tell
> ```

In order to toggle the state of the picture's visibility, simply apply standard boolean logic.  In case you're not familiar with this, it's basically the notion that ***true*** and ***false*** are mutually-exclusive (i.e. something cannot be both *true* and *false*), and they are each the other's inverse (i.e. something that is ***not*** *true* must therefore be *false*, and something that is ***not*** *false* must therefore be *true*).

In many programming and scripting languages, the boolean values of *true* and *false* are commonly represented by constants of the same name.  In AppleScript, as you already know, these constants are ***`true`*** and ***`false`***.  There are a trio of boolean *operators*, ***`and`***, ***`or`***, and ***`not`***.  The last one of these operators is the key to implementing a state toggle, on the basis that:

```
not true = false
```

and:

```
not false = true
```

---

Borrowing the references from your script, toggling works on the underlying principle of evaluating the property to discern its present state, and then assigning a new value to reflect the opposing state.  Here's the logic laid out in full:

```
if the visible of g = true then

        set the visible of g to false

else if the visible of g = false then

        set the visible of g to true

end
```

This is one instance where AppleScript's *"natural language"* paradigm does precisely what it says, so this is hopefully self-explanatory.  (This is not always going to be be the case, just to warn you.)

While this is perfectly ready to cut and paste into your script, there's a few things we can do to clean it up a bit, one of which I alluded to earlier, namely using the `not` operator to reduce some of the repetitive exposition of logic that can become tiresome.

`not` is acts upon a single boolean value, and gives us back the opposite (or *negated*) value, e.g:

```
not true
```

**Result:** *`false`*

Applying this to one half of the logic from previously, this:

```
if the visible of g = true then set the visible of g to false
```

is equivalent to this:

```
if the visible of g = true then set the visible of g to not true
```

Likewise, the same applies to the second half of the logic in an identical fashion:

```
if the visible of g = false then set the visible of g to not false
```

The `not` operator needn't only be applied to the explicit `true` and `false` constants.  After all, if this test is passed:

```
if the visible of g = true
```

this implies that `visible of g`—which is *equal* to `true`—is, therefore, itself a boolean value.  We can thus apply the `not` operator directly to the property itself:

```
if the visible of g = true then set the visible of g to not visible of g
```

Likewise, for the opposing start state:

```
if the visible of g = false then set the visible of g to not visible of g
```

Thus, what initially seemed like two separate conditions being evaluated, and two distinct outcomes being catered for by our code, is, in fact, functionally a singular process that acts upon the state in an identical fashion irrespective of what the initial value of the state is.

What this means is that we need never have to know the starting state in order to effect a toggle, and therefore, we don't actually have to test it at all.  We can simply do this:

```
set the visible of g to not visible of g
```

---

Inserting this back into you original script, we get this toggling capability:

```
tell application "GeekTool Helper"
      set g to geeklet id "C50F8977-88DF-4813-82C3-23D1C23F4624"
      set visible of g to not visible of g
end tell
```

Whilst we're done with respect to implementing the logic, we can also clean up the references to the `visible` property a little bit in much the same way as we did with the boolean expressions above.  From hereon, the principles will be much more specific to AppleScript, although it's by no means the only language which defines a clear ownership hierarchy for the various elements that appear in a script.  For your script, we begin at the very top-level that isn't immediately obvious, but it always present: that's the `AppleScript` instance itself, which is represented by the enumerated value assigned to the constant *`current application`*.  Everything else in a script is ultimately owned by the `current application`.

Moving down a level, one of the `current application`'s immediate descendants is the `application` class object for the *GeekTool Helper* app.  This is where relationships and ownership becomes more overt in the code, as AppleScript provides the keyword ***`tell`*** in order for us to access the child objects belonging to an element.  So moving down another level, we encounter the `geeklet` class object, which is the direct descendant of the *GeekTool Helper* `application` object.  Finally, in our case, this brings us to one of likely many properties belonging to any `geeklet` class object, in this case, the `visible` property that reports on as well as dictates back the visibility of the picture referenced by the `geeklet` element.

The point of this hierarchy is exemplified in the way you've enclosed the progeny of an `application` class object within a singular *`tell`* block, which forwards any statements that arise to the `application` element without the need to continuously reference the parent object every time we wish to access one of its children.  It's not so obvious how convenient this ends up being because your script is very short.  Nonetheless, I'm going to milk it for all its worth, and I'll start by removing the declaration of the variable `g` and, instead, *`tell`*-ing the `geeklet` element what to do:

```
tell application "GeekTool Helper"
      tell geeklet id "C50F8977-88DF-4813-82C3-23D1C23F4624"
            set visible to not visible
      end tell
end tell
```

Since this new `tell` block creates an enclosure similar to the one it itself lives in, commands will get forwarded onto the `geeklet` without having to be explicit about referring to it each time.  This is why we no longer require to say `visible of g` (or `visible of geeklet id "..."`), and we can just focus on the property that we intend to manipulate.

As each of the `tell` blocks only contains a single line or a single block, these can be collapsed into a single-line, compound `tell` statement by way of the ***`to`*** joiner:

```
tell application "GeekTool Helper" to tell geeklet id ¬
        "C50F8977-88DF-4813-82C3-23D1C23F4624" to set ¬
        visible to not visible
```

It still looks like three lines, but it's one line divided over three lines mostly for readability.  The continuation character (`¬`) lets AppleScript know to continue reading the next line as it's part of the same instruction.

For the final step, let's put this into a *handler*, which will allow this toggling functionality to become a generalised tool that can be used to toggle any `geeklet` whose `id` value is given to the handler:

```
to toggle(uuid)
        tell application "GeekTool Helper" to tell ¬
                geeklet id uuid to set visible to ¬
                not visible
end toggle
```

This can appear anywhere in your script, although it's sensible to put it (and any other handlers you create yourself in the future) at the bottom of the script, together in one place.  To make us of it, you simply call it with the `id` value of the `geeklet` object to be toggled:

```
toggle("C50F8977-88DF-4813-82C3-23D1C23F4624")
```

---

#### FIN ◻︎

```
toggle("C50F8977-88DF-4813-82C3-23D1C23F4624")
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
to toggle(uuid)
        tell application "GeekTool Helper" to tell ¬
                geeklet id uuid to set visible to ¬
                not visible
end toggle
```

Comment: Wow man - I was not expecting that detailed of an answer but I really appreciate. I have to do some minor scripting with some of my music software but outside of that I was pretty much in the dark. Anyhow REALLY appreciate you and anxious to see what else I can come up with